# Db2 data movement across different linux machines

Tags: database, db2, data-migration

We are planning to move to a new server, and we have installed db2 9.7 on it.

Which is the best option to move all the data from the db in the old server to the new server.

Both the servers have linux as OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an **offline backup** of the old server's db and **scp** it to the new server

In the new server, create a **new** database and **restore** the database with old server's backup

Comment: i am not able to restore, i have taken the back up and scp to the new server. how to create a new database in linux box? i do not have a gui.

i was told by some one that we need not create the destination db same as source as it will be done automatically by the restore. operation.

if i run the restore command say :
db2 RESTORE DATABASE wsdb FROM /dev3/backup 
    TAKEN AT 20020331234149

it says 
SQL1051N  The path "/data/home/db2inst1" does not exist or is not valid.
SQLSTATE=57019
Why is it looking in that path? however this path exists in source and not in destination machine

Comment: Assuming you have DB2 and db2inst1 instance ready in Destination. Lets say the database at source is `WSBD` and you created a database `WSBD1` in destination by `db2 create database WSBD1`. Now to restore just run this command: `db2 restore db WSBD from /dev3/backup TAKEN AT 20020331234149 on /home/db2inst1 into WSBD1`

Comment: I hope the endianess of both linux is the same (Linux on Power has different endianess).

Comment: For your issue, the best is to add the option "redirect generate script xxx.sql" and then modify the script with the right paths.

Comment: @Wasi i do not have db2inst1 in destination, i have db2inst6. i am not sure how to create one.

Comment: then log in as `db2inst6` then `db2 create database WSBD` and `db2 restore db WSBD from /dev3/backup TAKEN AT 20020331234149 on /home/db2inst6 into WSBD`

Comment: @AngocA i will try your suggestion. But i am not clear here if i have to create a new database at the destination? or will it be created automatically.

Comment: you need to.. basically you are creating a dummy database and restoring old db's data to that database

Comment: @Wasi Thanks a lot, it worked and the backup is successfull, 
i was able to connect it through toad, but i have one last issue,
when i try to do a select using db2inst6 it says :



ERROR [42501] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0551N  "DB2INST6" does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform operation "SELECT" on object "abc.table".  SQLSTATE=42501

When i check the users tab in toad it shows db2inst1, there is no db2inst6.

Comment: in the users tab in toad, i have an option to create a user and clone an existing user, should i create db2inst6 by cloning db2inst1? or os there a different standard procedure to provide authorization to db2inst6.

Comment: to the database on destination, log in as db2inst1 and grant all privileges to db2inst6

Comment: In the linux box of destination, i created a user db2inst1, then i am able to login to toad with db2inst1 and view data. But how to add privileges to db2inst6? Also in the control center i am not able to see any servers and databases(even when i click add new server and search for it).not sure why?. I installed db2 with db2setup command.

One more question is that During installation it never asked me to create a db2 administrator credentials, How to we create an administrator?

Comment: @Wasi i see these errors in db2install.history file, hope this may help u answer the previous comment: <br/>

ERROR: An error occurred during the execution of the command
"/data/db2/ibm/db2/V9.7/instance/dascrt  -u dasusr3 -d". The DB2 Administration
Server may not function properly. The return value is "1".

ERROR: ## call function cleanup_reg_list das crt dasusr3
## exit function cleanup_reg_list
DBI1103E  The Administration Server already exists.<br/>

Comment: @Wasi: ERROR: One or more errors occurred while creating the DB2 Administration
Server. The DB2 Administration Server may not function properly. Create the DB2
Administration Server manually. If the problem persists contact your technical
service representative.

Creating the DB2 Administration Server :.......Failure <br/>

ERROR: An error occurred while updating the configuration parameter
"DASADM_GROUP" to "dasadm1" for the DB2 Administration Server. The return value
is "-8050".

Comment: @Wasi :ERROR: An error occurred while running the command
"/data/db2/home/db2inst6/sqllib/bin/db2 CREATE TOOLS CATALOG SYSTOOLS USE
EXISTING DATABASE TOOLSDB FORCE" to initialize and/or upgrade the DB2 tools
catalog database. The return value is "4".<br/>


Please suggest some solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

it says SQL1051N The path "/data/home/db2inst1" does not exist or is not valid.

You need to do a redirected restore for destination Server with paths/mount points available on this server/machine.